# ReactJS: Autosave on fields within an accordion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI Accordions and am trying to auto save the fields when the accordions are open.

Currently I am using a button within each accordion (x5 - each button has a different class name):

```
<Accordion>
<AccordionSummary
expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
aria-controls="panel1a-content"
id="panel1a-header"
>
<Typography className={classes.heading}>Heading</Typography>
</AccordionSummary>
<AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
          <form>
          ...
            <Button
              disableElevation
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={(e) => onSubmit(e)}
              color="default"
              size="large"
              type="submit"
              className="btn2"
              startIcon={<SaveAltTwoToneIcon />}
            >
              Save
            </Button>
          </form>
          </Typography>
</AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

I am then using:

```
let intervalID2;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value == 2) {
      intervalID2 = setInterval(() => {
        const formSubmitButton = document.querySelectorAll(".btn2, .btn3, .btn4, .btn5, .btn6");
        if (formSubmitButton != null) {
          formSubmitButton.forEach(el=>el.click())
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID2);
  }, [value == 2]);
```

To loop through each accordion to simulate the button click. Not ideal, but it sort of works - but the performance is super slow and I cannot actually click on anything else on the page. These accordions are all within the same tab as well.

How can I trigger the autosaving of the fields only when the accordion is open?

Comment: What are you trying to autosave? Can you explain a bit more what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Just simple textfields - <TextField enterTouchDelay={0} type="number" defaultValue="0" InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }} inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric' }} id="standard-basic" label="ABC" value={abc} onChange={(e) => e.target.value === "" && def !== 0 ? setABC(0) : setABC(e.target.value)} name="ABC"  variant="outlined" />

Comment: See my answer. Can you clarify what you mean by saving it? Making it so its the same value when they go back to the accordion, or saving it between routes/to the backend/something else?

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the Dom and extracting values isn't a "React" way to do things.

See [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), specifically the section on controlled components.

You want to have a state for each text field, where the state is linked to the current value of the field. So e.g.:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("")

return <Textfield value={EMAIL} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value}> // note value, not defaultValue

That way, the state is always "saved" in the component state. I'm not 100% sure what you meant by saved though. If you meant saved if they go to another route, you could save to Redux state. If you meant saved if they refresh the page, you could save to local storage. You could do these by having a useEffect that has the field state be in the dependency array, so it gets invoked whenever the field changes, and save the logic there.

If you meant save to the backend, and want to batch it so it only does that when the accordion is closed, you could have a useEffect that has the accordion state as a dependency, that gets called when true accordion changes. You could keep track of the last open accordion with a state or useRef, and upload all the state in the previously open accordion.

If I'm misunderstanding the question, let me know!
```